# php mysql check existing syntax

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have an ordering system from 1 to 6 (both inclusive), which the order number is assigned to a news in table `featured` by user's choice. When a user saves an order for a news, in the table `featured` is inserted a new row with these fields: `id_news`, `id_user`, `id_category` and `order`

What I am looking for is for a better syntax to check if there already is a news for client `X` with order `Y`.

Right now I'm doing each thing in a separate query, with these actions:

1. User chooses to feature news 1241 to order number 3
2. Script checks to see if there exists any news for client `X` with order number 3
3. If exists, it deletes it
4. Add the new featured news.

Anyway of making all that in less actions/code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Assuming `(id_user,order)` is a unique key, then you can just insert the new value and, if the order already exists, update it with the new `id_news`.

```
INSERT INTO `featured` VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id_news`=VALUES(`id_news`)
```

Comment: So that would change my `id_news`'s order value with the new `id_news`?

Comment: Another way around it if (id_user, order) is not unique, you can run an update statement and check for affected rows, if no rows were affected, then you run the insert statement.

Comment: @Ateszki it's kinda the same thing as the response above, only some more php interaction. Thanks anyway, for your suggestion

Comment: indeed, it is almost the same, but it helps you if you don't have or don't want the unique index. You are welcome.